# Importing android source code as a project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have downloaded an android sample called custom view from android refernce from this location

> http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/CustomView.zip

It only has the java files and other resources but does not contain any project file for me to import in eclipse as a project.

So when I import existing project into workspace, eclipse does not pick the project in the import dialog.

How can I import it into eclipse ? I have ADT tools installed already,

Thanks, 
Ahmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that's because you'll have to make the manifest.xml file.

What I'd suggest, is to create a new Android project, with the same package and Activity's name than in your zip (ie `com.example.android.customviews` and `MainActivity`), then copy/paste the files from your zip to the new project directory (`thus replacing`src`and`res` folders). That way, Eclipse will generate the manifest for you, with correct reference.

This should not take more than 30 seconds...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Explorer and right click -> Import -> Select Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace -> browse to folder with your code -> finish

Comment: I have tried this but does not work, the finish button remains disabled , I tried pointing to custom-view folder as well as src folder but to not avail

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I did thought that it's missing the AndroidManifest.xml file. I tried to fixed it and place it [here](https://github.com/inspire365/android-customviews-fixed). You can download it an try.